# Visual Studio 2010 - Intellisense for jQuery 1.4.4

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010, vsdoc

I tried going through some of the other questions here at Stack, aswell as searching google but i mostly get hits in korean/japanese/chinese.

Anywho im running VS2010
its a MVC3 Project, im using a _layout masterpage
using jQuery 1.4.4 along with a matching vsdoc for that version (downloaded today from MS so it should be the newest).

This is the content of the _layout page im using: http://pastebin.com/fB6FzaLS
Not sure if its needed or not, but i added the code to enable the jQuery vsdoc (and the path is correct).

Whenever i Ctrl+Space the dot after the jQuery pointer i get this error in my output panel:

**Javascript Intellisense Message: JSIntellisense:Internal/window(2:4) : Function expected**

The intellisense suggestions it comes up with are extremely generic (constructor, valueof etc. about 7 ish in total)

In Extension manager i have disabled everything but the VisualStudio JScript enhancements (brackets, word highligther etc)

Any ideas what might be the problem here?

Comment: I like this question because I cannot find any tips on making .js scripts JSIntellisense-friendly.  Our scripts work correctly at run-time, but the lack of accurate intellisense is dearly missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering whether you're getting a conflict with the two instances of jQuery.

Two observations. Firstly, if all you're looking for is simple intellisense, VS2010 will do a very good job with the default jQuery reference. That said, I think your problem would be resolved by moving your JS into an external script file, and adding a reference to the VSDOC into that file instead.

Incidentally, jQuery 1.5.1 is out if you're looking for the most up to date version.

Rich

Comment: Maybe you could create a project with a configuration you know intellisense works on. If i still cant get that to work then the problem isnt with the project setup. By the way, what do you mean with the default jQuery refference? If visual studio 2010 is suppose to show it by default then something must be switched off. Can it be enabled or disabled?

Comment: @kim3er I Think I probably do as you suggest have more than one jQuery file referenced, but before I delve into each and every folder in my scripts folder (lots of widgets and plugins etc) am wondering ... "answer" below

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting lots of

```
Javascript Intellisense Message :
```

I my output window when I try to validate my JavaScript in VS 2010 e.g.

```
Javascript Intellisense Message: [LocalPath]\jquery-1.5.1.js(6357:32) : Function expected
```

... etc and e.g.

```
: 'Sys' is undefined 
: Object required
```

for files including

```
\jquery-1.5.1.js
\tiny_mce.js
```

and custom scripts files.

Wondering if people have any general advice on what sort of things can cause this?

And how to work out the root causes when you (like me) have a) checked all the obvious & easy bits, and b) have lots and lots of script files, and c) lots of references e.g.

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/custom/core.js" />
```

(in an attempt to get back the time you put into XML commenting your custom JS to pay off **fully**)

Comment: yeah - installed 2012 ;) I did solve this actually, but can't remember what it was... think it was some setting in VS options.